# iOS scroll view disable auto scroll to top

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I'm new to iOS development so this should probably be a easy question for someone.
I am creating a scrollview (tried different ways, UIScrollView, UITableView, UITableViewController) and everytime i scroll down it scrolls back up to the top automatically. Why does this happen?

I understand "scrollsToTop" is listening for some guesture to scroll to top but that is set to NO so should not be that.
"pagingEnabled" have been tested to be YES and NO but does not have an impact.

Tried to implement a UITableViewDelegate and override the scrollViewShouldSrollToTop function and return NO but the function is never called even though it is set as delegate of the tableView.

```
@interface Scroller : NSObject<UITableViewDelegate>

@implementation
- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView )scrollView {return NO;}

// Did finish launching application
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableRect style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
self->tableView.pagingEnabled = NO;
tableView.scrollsToTop = NO;
[tableView setScrollsToTop:NO]; 
static Scroller s = [[Scroller alloc] init];
tableView.delegate = s;
```

Dont mind the formatting. It's all a mess. 
tableView belongs to the application delegate and is called in the ..didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:... function.
I have a breakpoint in the Scroller function "scrollViewShouldScrollToTop" but it is never hit.

Comment: At what point does it scroll back up? Is there a delay, or does it spring back immediately?

Comment: It springs back immediately. When I let go of the screen it springs right back to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use UIScrollView instead of UITableView and set the contentSize to something bigger then the view frame and then it works. Still don't know what the problem with UITableView is though.

Answer (score 6):

Auto scroll to top could happen maybe if you are tapping on the top bar (the black one)? In any case you can try to disable that feature -

`[yourScrollView].scrollsToTop = NO;`

this should apply to `tableView` or `scrollView`

Comment: Sorry, that does not work for me. It is set to NO but nothing changes. Also tried self->[myScrollView].scrollsToTop = NO and [[myScrollView] setScrollsToTop:NO]. Maybe there is something with the delegate? Nothing is assigned to the delegate property.

Comment: can you show me some code or some screenshots? its difficult to throw darts on bullseye in a dark room...

Comment: Is there any way by which we can disable this for whole app ?

Answer (score 0):

When there is not enough items to fill all height in `UITableView` - it will scroll back every time.
Also you should set contentSize property for `UIScrollView` to make it scrollable.

Scroll to top mentioned before should happened when user taps on status bar. But as i understand it's not your problem.

Comment: I think your right about scroll to top is not my problem. Right now I fill the tableView with UIButtons and there are more buttons then the window can show (it shows 6 vertically and there are 12).
I have tried setting the contentSize but that did not change anything either. I am adding the buttons by doing [tableView addSubView:button]; I also tried [tableView insertSubview:button atIndex:0]; Maybe this is the problem. The button is not a subview but a item/object? But I can not find any other function to add stuff to the tableView.

Answer (score -1):

You Should disable the bouncing property of scroll view set it to NO in Inrterface builder.